# How to broadcast on a single index in hierarchically indexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a hierarchically indexed data frame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4),
                      index=[['John', 'John', 'Vicki', 'Vicki'], 
                             ['a','b', 'a','b']],
                      columns=['score'])

         score
John  a      0
      b      1
Vicki a      2
      b      3
```

and a series with index identical to the first index level in the above data frame:

```
>>> series = pd.Series([100, 200], index=['John', 'Vicki'])

John     100
Vicki    200
```

Now I want to merge the data frame with the series, such that the values from the series are broadcasted along the second level index. The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
         score  salary
John  a      0     100
      b      1     100
Vicki a      2     200
      b      3     200
```

How can I achieve that in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['salary'] = series.reindex(df.index, level=0)
```

Comment: It looks like you were calling `reset_index` in the issue.